# Maximum And minimum value of a determinant

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

I have come across a trick to find the max/min value of a determinant, but I want to confirm if it is true, at least for a $3 \times 3$ matrix determinant.

> If $$|A| = \begin{vmatrix}
> a1 & b1 & c1\\
> a2 & b3 & c2\\
> a3 & b3 & c3
> \end{vmatrix}$$
> where $a_{i},\ b_{i},c_{i} \in \{ \alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}, \dots, \alpha_{n} \}$, then

- $\max|A|$ when diagonals elements are $\min\{\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}, \dots, \alpha_{n}\}$, and also all the other elements are $\max\{\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \dots, \alpha_{n}\}$.
- $\min|A| = -\max|A|$

Please confirm this result.

- P.S: I have tried a few examples and it does seem to work but still need assurance.

Comment: What are $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ ?

Comment: some set, the elements in the matrix should belong to this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your set of $\alpha$'s is $\{-1,0\}$, then $\det(A)=-1$ when the diagonals $=\min(\{-1,0\})=-1$ and the other entries $=\max(\{-1,0\})=0$.
Whereas $\det(A)=0$, when $a_2, a_3=0$ and the other entries are $-1$.
Therefore you have a determinant larger than the one obtained with your technique, where not all non-diagonal entries are equal to $\max\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$